# PySpark structured streaming read Kafka to delta table

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-live-tables

Exploring PySpark Structured Streaming and databrick. I want to write a spark structural streaming job to read all the data from a kafka topic and publish to delta tables.

Let's assume I'm using latest version and kafka has following details.

kafka topic name: ABC
kafka broker: localhost:9092
sample data: name=qwerty&company_name=stackoverflow&profession=learner

I want to store the kafka topic data in the delta table with the following fields:

timestamp, company_name, data
2022-11-14 07:50:00+0000, StackOverflow, name=qwerty&company_name=stackoverflow&profession=learner

Is there a way that I can see delta table data in console?

Comment: Is there a way that I can see delta table data in console - which console are you referring to? Also, you can view delta table data by writing simple pyspark code.

Comment: When I run spark-submit on CLI/Mac Terminal instead of in databricks.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and display your data using spark. Something like:

```
people_df = spark.read.load(table_path)

display(people_df)
# or
people_df.show(5)
```

Then you can submit this like any other spark job. Refer to [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/tutorial.html#read-a-table) for more details.